# What's the difference between returning a reference and value when overloading operator=?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Look here:

```
class IntClass
{
public:
IntClass operator=(const IntClass& rhs);
IntClass();
~IntClass();
int value;

};
```

Implementation:

```
IntClass::IntClass()
{
}


IntClass::~IntClass()
{
}

IntClass IntClass::operator=(const IntClass& rhs)
{
    this->value = rhs.value;
    return *this;
}
```

As you can see I am not returning a reference to the class. From the examples of overloading the = operator I see that people return a reference. Why is this?

This still functions as intended:

```
IntClass a, b, c, d;

a.value = 20;

b = c = d = a;

printf("%d", b.value);
printf("%d", c.value);
printf("%d", d.value);
```

Output: 202020

p.s I know the public access to value is bad.

Comment: Returning a value gives you a copy.

Comment: and returning a reference returns the actual data-field. Thats about it. Google would'ne answered that in 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but if I am copying the value from rhs to the instance it shouldn't matter. The only thing I can think of is if this is a huge class passing a new copy would be expensive. A reference would be cheaper.

Comment: indeed, thats about the reason. Plus : in exotic environments one might want to lock on shared memory-pages, which are then modified in turn by several threads ... its the most efficient way, simple as that.

Comment: Returning reference makes the result of assignment an lvalue (mimics the built-in assignment operator). Returning a copy makes the result an rvalue. This can have interesting consequences. For example, `void f(IntClass &x); IntClass x, y; f(x = y);` only compiles if your `operator=` returns a reference.

Comment: A reference is the memory address of a variable or a pointer, while value is a copy of the actual data or value. When you are returning an instance of a class, you return a pointer to and not a reference to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, having your assignment operator return by value means that you are making an extra copy. The copy can be expensive, and compilers usually cannot elide it. If we assume that copy assignment and copy construction have roughly the same cost, then returning by value basically doubles the cost of the assignment.

Second, if your assignment operator return a reference, the result of the assignment expression is an lvalue, which mimics the built-in assignment operator. If your assignment operator return by value, the result of the expression is an rvalue. This can have interesting consequences:

```
void f(IntClass &lv); 
void g(IntClass &&rv);
void g(const IntClass &clv);

IntClass x, y; 
y.value = 10;
f(x = y);  // compiles only if operator= returns IntClass & 
           // as non-const lvalue references cannot bind to a temporary
g(x = y);  // calls g(IntClass &&) if operator= returns IntClass
           // calls g(const IntClass &) if operator= returns IntClass &
```

Comment: Returning a reference implies that the object must exist after exiting the function, such as a static variable in a function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't think that's particularly relevant for assignment operators.